# CSS Properties aspect-ratio vs object-fit

Tags: css, image

I am a little new to CSS. I am trying to apply to an image a 16:9 ratio.

I have seen both the `object-fit` and `aspect-ration` properties.

Do I need the `object-fit` property if I just use the `aspect-ratio: 16/9` property ?

I did read an article [New aspect-ratio CSS property](https://web.dev/aspect-ratio/#example-consistency-in-a-grid) and the writer uses both.

Can someone please clarify this?

Comment: What does 'apply a 16:9 ratio to an image' mean? Do you mean you want any image with any natural aspect ratio to show just enough of itself to cover a 16:9 space (e.g. cover) or do you want a 16:9 space with the whole of the image shown inside it (e.g. contain)?

Comment: The first one (cover), so that I do not have any white space within the container. Thanks to Jon Uleis I did understand, that I would have to also use `object-fit: cover;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of why you would want to combine `aspect-ratio` with `object-fit`: So your image doesn't get stretched.

You can control the composition within the newly specified aspect ratio using `object-fit` and `object-position`.

```css
img {
  border: 2px solid red;
  width: 190px;
}

label {
  display: inline-block;
}

span {
  display: block;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-align: center;
}

.ar {
  aspect-ratio: 16/9;
}

.of {
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<label>
<img src="https://www.englishclub.com/images/kids/shapes-615.png" />
<span>no aspect-ratio or object-fit</span>
</label>

<label>
<img class="ar" src="https://www.englishclub.com/images/kids/shapes-615.png" />
<span>aspect-ratio: 16/9</span>
</label>

<label>
<img class="ar of" src="https://www.englishclub.com/images/kids/shapes-615.png" />
<span>aspect-ratio: 16/9 + object-fit: cover</span>
</label>
```

Comment: I couldn't have asked for a better explanation. Thank you!